# How to split series then add them into a new column in an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I split the output which is in a list form into individual rows?

The last column is derived from applying a custom function groupby A, B, C. There is no column header for the last column after applying the groupby function

```
A          B  C       
202311     X  Y       [147.01, 140.01, 133.01, 126.01, 119.01, 112.0...
202312     X  Y       [175, 168, 161, 154, 147, 140, 133, 126, 119, ...
202313     X  Y       [175, 168, 161, 154, 147, 140, 133, 126, 119, ...
202314     X  Y       [175, 168, 161, 154, 147, 140, 133, 126, 119, ...
202315     X  Y       [175, 168, 161, 154, 147, 140, 133, 126, 119, ...
202316     X  Y       [95.09, 88.09, 81.09, 74.09, 67.09, 60.09, 53....
202317     X  Y       [60.1, 53.1, 46.1, 39.1, 32.1, 25.1, 18.1, 11....
202318     X  Y       [57.02, 50.02, 43.02, 36.02, 29.02, 22.02, 15....
202319     X  Y       [43.31, 36.31, 29.31, 22.31, 15.31, 8.31, 1.31...
202320     X  Y       [66.84, 59.84, 52.84, 45.84, 38.84, 31.84, 24....
202321     X  Y       [175, 168, 161, 154, 147, 140, 133, 126, 119, ...
202322     X  Y       [155.18, 148.18, 141.18, 134.18, 127.18, 120.1...
202323     X  Y       [170.63, 163.63, 150.18, 143.18, 136.18, 129.1...
```

Desired outcome:

```
A          B  C       D     E
202311     X  Y       202311    147.01
202311     X  Y       202312    140.01
202311     X  Y       202313    133.01  
202311     X  Y       202314    126.01
202311     X  Y       202315    119.01
202311     X  Y       202316    112.0
202311     X  Y       202317    ..
202311     X  Y       202318    ..
202312     X  Y       202312    175
202312     X  Y       202313    168
202312     X  Y       202314    161
202312     X  Y       202315    154
202312     X  Y       202316    147
```

Column D is existing column.

Thank you!

Tried
`df['E'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).apply(lambda d: customfunction(d['X'], d['Y']).str.split(',')`

Error Message:
`incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Comment: Don't call `tolist`. Describe what you're actually trying to accomplish and show your code for the custom function, as well as (at least an excerpt of) your original data, not the data after the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example Code**

Your example is not minimal and reproducible. [Plz provide a minimal and reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Including omissions in input, such as (...), is also a typical bad example. Create an example with completeness.

Let's create a new example for explanation.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':[202311, 202312, 202313], 'B':'X', 'C':'Y', 
        'col':[[147, 140, 133], [175, 168, 161], [120, 140, 160]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df:

[image]

---

**Code**

use `explode` and make column by `groupby + cumcount` after explode

```
out = df.explode('col')\
        .assign(D=lambda x: x.groupby('A').cumcount().add(x['A']))\
        .reindex(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'col'], axis=1).rename(columns={'col':'E'})
```

out:

```
    A       B   C   D       E
0   202311  X   Y   202311  147
0   202311  X   Y   202312  140
0   202311  X   Y   202313  133  
1   202312  X   Y   202312  175   <-- start with 202312
1   202312  X   Y   202313  168
1   202312  X   Y   202314  161
2   202313  X   Y   202313  120   <-- start with 202313
2   202313  X   Y   202314  140
2   202313  X   Y   202315  160
```